# Is there a desktop application for managing vector/image files and other graphics?

Tags: software-rec, graphics

I have a huge and growing graphics file collection, which I store in the folders. I wonder if there is a special tool for designers to tag and search these images. Editing is not necessary.. For instance, I would like to find an image, which contains cats, or only white/black colors instead of browsing my 500gb folder structure manually...

Comment: Adobe bridge is a good program for adding metadata, and searching and filtering through files. Supports all image formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google's Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) is free and will let you tag your images and [search for colours](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=19859). It can even use [face-matching](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=156272) to recognise who is in your pictures. It does not support vector graphics though, so if you really need that, you might want go for Adobe Bridge. (As suggested by JFW) It's not free though and comes with the Creative Suite 5.

#### Colour searching:

[image: Colour searching]

#### Face-matching:

[image: Face-matching screenshot]